# What is the WebGLActiveInfo function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

In Chrome, open your JavaScript console and you will find `WebGLActiveInfo` as a global variable. I've tried looking for documentation on this function but nothing comes up.

Naively calling it will produce a `TypeError: Illegal constructor`, which is frustrating because it's a black box:

```
function WebGLActiveInfo() { [native code] }
```

What does this function do? How can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a function, it's the name of a native Object. Same as `WebGLRenderingContext`, `WebGLTexture`, `Blob`, or `XMLHTTPRequest`. Type any of those and you'll get the same function signature.

`WebGLActiveInfo` objects are returned from `gl.getActiveUniform` and `gl.getActiveAttrib`

Comment: It is a function — it's just useless to call. All explicit object types in JavaScript are represented as constructor functions.

Comment: I'd argue any function you can't call is not a function. Even if it's labelled as such. It's not even a constructor. You can't go `new WebGLTexture();` or `new WebGLActiveInfo();` though I suppose you could argue it is a function defined as `WebGLActiveInfo = function() { throw TypeError("Illegal constructor"); };`